# Number of columns in a Flow in QML

Tags: qt, qml, qt5, qtquick2

In my QML application in Qt 5.9 I would like to show [Rectangle](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-rectangle.html)s with a fixed width in a [Flow](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-flow.html). In order to keep the layout centered I try to adjust its padding dynamically. To calculate the right value though I need to know the current number of columns, say **colCount**. Is there a way to get it?

Here is a code example of what I would like to do using the pseudo variable **colCount**:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Example")

    Flow {
        anchors.fill: parent
        leftPadding: parent.width > 200*colCount ? 0.5*(parent.width - 200*colCount) : 0
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The magic of posting :) Shortly after I've manage to figure that out and I post the solution here for someone who might need it.

There is a property [childrenRect.width](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-item.html#childrenRect.width-prop) inherited from *Item* which could come in handy. So the number of columns *colCount* could be calculated as `childrenRect.width / w`, where *w* is the width of a child (it should be the same for all children of the *FLOW* for this one to work).

In the code example from the question:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.3

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 800
    height: 600
    title: qsTr("Example")

    Flow {
        anchors.fill: parent
        leftPadding: parent.width > childrenRect.width ? 0.5*(parent.width - childrenRect.width) : 0
        spacing: 0

        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "red"
        }

        Rectangle {
            width: 200
            height: 200
            color: "blue"
        }
    }
}
```